# How to update user credentials after setupIntent succeed in Stripe API (Node.js + React)

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, stripe-payments

I have scenario where users setting their payment credentials in Profile setting page using PaymentElement (mostly simple card detaild number, year, cvv). Before that I bind customer (user) with new SetupIntent (on successful signup) and then send secret from them for Elements (wrapper around PaymentElement) in Profile setting page.
I want to get ability that users can change/update/delete their payment credentials. I tried to change SetupIntent but it prevents changed due to 'success' status.
How to make it in proper way?

1. user sends POST request on completion of sign up
2. then on backend I make stripe.customers.create -> stripe.setupIntents.create(customerId) -> save setupIntent id in db
3. user signed in into account, opens settings page with stripe PaymentElemets
4. client requests to get client_secret (from back using setupIntents.retrieve(id)) for Elements (around PaymentElemets)
5. user fills payment details -> stripe.confirmSetup (on client) -> setupIntent becomes 'success'
6. ...then, I wonder how to handle case user want to change payment credentials in proper way.

all according to official doc tutorial https://docs.stripe.com/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=web&ui=elements#set-up-stripe.js

Comment: Could you describe the steps you are taking in a bulleted list with the specific API requests you are making?  It is hard from your description to understand the sequence of what is happening and that will be important to getting the correct advice.

Comment: Please update your question, not in a comment.  If you update the actual question text it will respect markdown formatting and make this easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what you mean when you say "change payment credentials".  However, once a Payment Method of type "card" is saved, you can only update the expiration data and networks as the [API reference doc](https://docs.stripe.com/api/payment_methods/update#update_payment_method-card) shows.

If the user wishes to change the card number you must create a new Payment Method.

Comment: I tried, but cant figure out how to change card number via creating new Payment Method. instead of stripe.confirmSetup({elements}) I use stripe.createPaymentMethod({elements}) but I got errors after elements.submit() 'IntegrationError: To use createPaymentMethod with the Payment Element, your elements instance must be created with paymentMethodCreation: 'manual'.'. I cant find this option

Comment: I thought about next logic: any time user fills  and confirm stripe payment element it just updates its payment method id to the existing setupIntent (which was already created on sign up )

Comment: I use element in react   const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();

Comment: Can you share the exact steps you are taking (with code examples) and the exact error message you receive?

Comment: I decided to create new setupIntent each time user wants to change card number or any other payment method. I think it will work. I thought setupIntents must be cleared if they are unused, and this require difficult logic to manage their clearing. actually setupIntent will clear by stripe after 7 days, so you don't need to care about that.